# Optimising the generation of a large number of random numbers using python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, random, numbers

I am wanting to generate eight random numbers within a range (0 to pi/8), add them together, take the sine of this sum, and after doing this N times, take the mean result. After scaling this up I get the correct answer, but it is too slow for `N > 10^6`, especially when I am averaging over N trials `n_t = 25` more times! I am currently getting this code to run in around *12 seconds* for `N = 10^5`, meaning that it will take *20 minutes* for `N = 10^7`, which doesn't seem optimal (it may be, I don't know!).

My code is as follows:

```
import random
import datetime
from numpy import pi
from numpy import sin
import numpy
t1 = datetime.datetime.now()

def trial(N):
    total = []
    uniform = numpy.random.uniform
    append = total.append
    for j in range(N):
        sum = 0
        for i in range (8):
            sum+= uniform(0, pi/8)
        append(sin(sum))
    return total

N = 1000000
n_t = 25
total_squared = 0
ans = []
for k in range (n_t):
    total = trial(N)
    f_mean = (numpy.sum(total))/N
    ans.append(f_mean*((pi/8)**8)*1000000)
sum_square = 0
for e in ans:
    sum_square += e**2
sum = numpy.sum(ans)
mean = sum/n_t
variance = sum_square/n_t - mean**2
s_d = variance**0.5
print (mean, " ± ", s_d)
t2 = datetime.datetime.now()
print ("Execution time: %s" % (t2-t1))
```

If anyone can help me optimise this it would be much appreciated!

Thank you :)

Comment: What's the end goal? If it's just computing an average, do the math rather than a lengthy simulation that will suffer statistical error anyway.

Comment: So you want to generate 2 *billion* random numbers? That will certainly takes time.

Comment: Maybe a little speedup with `sum= numpy.sum(numpy.random.random_sample(8)) * pi_8`

Comment: @JulienBernu it is a Monte-Carlo approach to doing an eighth dimensional integral of sin(x_0 + x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 + x_7)dx_0...dx_7 with the range of each x being from 0 to pi/8

Comment: But why not doing it analytically? Using MC makes sense only when the analytical solution is intractable, which does not seem to be the case here...

Comment: @justhalf is that a bad idea?

Comment: @JulienBernu I know that, I've done it analytically, it should be (and is) 537.1873411, but I'm not so concerned about the answer as about how to get it using MC efficiently :)

Comment: @YvesDaoust I have tried that and am afraid that it doesn't seem to help!

Comment: I mean, 2 billion is a lot of numbers. Supposing you generate everything before calculation (like in the vectorized approach by Julien Bernu), it will take *at least* 8GB of memory. It's still ok (20 mins is not that long),  but you need some space and patience for this =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given your requirement of obtaining the result with this method, `np.sin(np.random.uniform(0,np.pi/8,size=(8,10**6,25)).sum(axis=0)).mean(axis=0)` gets you your 25 trials pretty quickly... This is fully vectorised (and concise which is always a bonus!) so I doubt you could do any better...

Explanation:

You generate a big random 3d array of size `(8 x 10**6 x 25)`. `.sum(axis=0)` will get you the sum over the first dimension (`8`). `np.sin(...)` applies elementwise. `.mean(axis=0)` will get you the mean over the first remaining dimension (`10**6`) and leave you with a 1d array of length (`25`) corresponding to your trials.

Comment: Thank you! How does this work and how do I implement this? Sorry, I only started learning python a week ago so I don't have much idea what I'm doing!

Comment: This will generate everything in memory first, right? So it will need at least 8GB for N=1e7. Still ok in some modern computers, but it is not that cheap in terms of memory. Nice approach on the vectors there, though. +1

Comment: worked in about 30s for 10**7 for me. If you are memory limited you can unvectorise the last dimension (n_trials=25) back into a basic `for` loop

Comment: Yes! numpy, scipy and other libraries already have a ton of efficiently implemented stuff. In your case, definitely use `.std()` or `.var()` as well!

Answer (score 1):

By the Central Limit Theorem, your random variable will closely follow a normal law.

The sum of the eight uniform variables has a bell-shaped distribution over the range [0, π]. If I am right, the distribution can be represented as a B-spline of order 8. Taking the sine gives a value in range [0, 1]. You can find the expectation µ and variance σ² by simple numerical integration.

Then use a normal generator with mean µ and variance σ²/N. That will be instantaneous in comparison.

Comment: well if you are going for math don't stop half way ;)

Comment: @JulienBernu: I am not stopping half way. I am telling the OP how he can generate a random variable that has the same characteristics as the one computed from 8N values. But it's still a random value.